# How can I search for a string value on a selected row in the datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I have DataGridView, and I've managed for it to work so that when the user clicks on a row, the program fills the correspondent text boxes with the data from that row.

I want it to auto check radioButton1 if the row contains 'exampleValue', else it should check radioButton2.

I always get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection' to 'bool'"

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I tried this here code

```
            if (dtgFunc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dtgFunc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
            {
                if ((string)cell.Value == "seller")
                {
                    rdbSeller.Checked = true;
                    rdbManager.Checked = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    rdbManager.Checked = true;
                    rdbSeller.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

But I still get this error. Thoughts?

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: @deathismyfriend posted it now, but I don't know how much it can help, because I'm coding in a different language. I was just wondering what would I use if I wanted to search for a specific value in a row, and then somehow convert that to boolean so I can make the _'if row contains 'xxx' then radioButton1.Checked = true'_ thing

Comment: You don't post what example value is or were you use it ? If you are looking for any column in the row contains it then you need to search through each cell in that row and convert the value to a string the do a comparison check on the cells to see if the row contains a certain string. Then you can check the radio button

Comment: @deathismyfriend I upted the original post with what I tried. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq:

```
yourDataGridViewCellCollection
   .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals(exampleValue)) != null
```

**Edit:**
I see you updated your post.
The error is thrown because some of your columns have integer value, and you try to cast their value to string.

Replace your loop with

```
if (dtgFunc.Rows[e.RowIndex]
   .Cells
   .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals("seller")) != null)
{
   rdbSeller.Checked = true;
   rdbManager.Checked = false;
}
else
{
   rdbManager.Checked = true;
   rdbSeller.Checked = false;
}
```

Or you can just change

```
(string)cell.Value == "seller"
```

in your current code to:

```
cell.Value.Equals("seller")
```

since cell.Value is an object it will check if types are compatible before comparing

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change

```
(String)cell.Value
```

To this

```
cell.Value.ToString();
```

It can't cast the value to string so you need to convert it using the above.